# Cant call a method from another script in C#? Using Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

Alright, I've asked around on the Unity3d forums with no luck. I'm attempting something pretty simple here and for some reason I can't get one C# script to call a function of another.

I am in Unity here and I have 2 scripts that I'm trying to use to detect a simple tap on a GameObject and do something based on that tap - OnMouseDown has failed me for whatever reason.

I read an article on using a TouchManager script attached to an empty to call a function from the touched object's script, so here is that ; it uses Raycasts and is supposed to get the touched game object and called the `Touched()` function:

```
protected virtual void Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 1) {

        if (Input.touches [0].phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.touches [0].position);
            if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit, 100.0f)) {
                touchedObject = hit.transform.gameObject; 
                touchedObject.GetComponent<touchableGameObject> ().Touched ();
                print (touchedObject.name);
            } else print ("GetMouseButtonDown on nothing");
        }
    }
}
```

Without the first if, I was getting an `OutofBounds` in the Array error. However now with that first if I am getting no results at all.

Then on my enemy prefab (which is clearly an object) I just have:

```
public void Touched() {
    print ("touched!! WORKING");
}
```

the function is public so it should be able to be called. I have a print in the Start() method so I know the script is working, yet the `Touched()` method is never called even when I am clearly touching/clicking on the game object.

Without the first if statement in the Touch Manager script, I would consistently get the last else if printed:

```
print ("GetMouseButtonDown on nothing");
```

I am relatively new to Unity and C# and cant figure this out. I need this to work and I'm desperate.

How does one call a function based on touch from another C# script?

Comment: Did you make sure that the supposedly touched gameObject have a collider?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple mistake.

When there is one touch, `Input.touchCount` is `1`. When there are `2`, the `Input.touchCount` value is 2.

*The problem with your code is on this line*: `if (Input.touchCount > 1) {`

You are **only** checking if touch is more than **1**.

You should be checking if touch is more or equals to **1** : `if (Input.touchCount >= 1)`

OR

If touch is more than `0`: `if (Input.touchCount > 0)`.

Any one of this should solve your problem.

Finally, it is not guaranteed that the touched GameObject will have the `touchableGameObject` script attached to it. Because of it this, you must check if `GetComponent<touchableGameObject>()` is `null` before calling its `Touched()` function. Please capitalize the name of your scripts. This will make it easier for you to identify a script and a variable name.

```
protected virtual void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
    {
        if (Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
            {
                touchedObject = hit.transform.gameObject;


                touchableGameObject touchScript = touchedObject.GetComponent<touchableGameObject>();
                if (touchScript != null)
                {
                    touchScript.Touched();
                }

                print(touchedObject.name);
            }
            else
            {
                print("GetMouseButtonDown on nothing");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but Im still having a big problem, this being that nothing is registered. Im not even getting the ""GetMouseButtonDown on nothing" - I just really need to detect touches on a game object. Have you ever done something like this?

Comment: If detecting a tap then change `TouchPhase.Stationary` to `TouchPhase.Began`.. Let me know what happens.

Comment: All Im getting is a bunch of "GetMouseButtonDown on nothing" whenever I click anywhere. Please help me

Comment: Why not upload your project somewhere then provide the link here.  I will take at what the problem is. By the way, are you even testing with a mobile device?

Comment: Yes I am - Im using Unity Remote. And the gameobject does have a collider. Thank you so much, Im just grabbing at loose strings here. Here is the github -https://github.com/UnfortunatelySome/PetaGame-master

Comment: Raycast does not work on current machin with Unity Remote. It works on my old computer. There is a bug with Unity Remote. Please test it with a physical mobile device. Build it and test it on your Android or iPhone. Make sure to replace `TouchPhase.Stationary` with `TouchPhase.Began`. If that doesn't work then I will take a look at it

Comment: I have built it for iOS and copied your code and still nothing happens. I have uploaded the most recent version here - github.com/UnfortunatelySome/PetaGame-master

Comment: Ok. What's suppose to happen when there is a touch on the gameobject? What does the `Touched()` function do?

Comment: The Touched func is in the touchableGameObject script attached to the guard prefab, which is one of the sectors. If you go to prefabs you will see it. As written above, it should print to the console and in the latest version I added that it destroys the touched game object

Comment: Did you download the project?